# Timing file open time with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to test how long it takes to load a large file (cad or PSD files) and currently our testers are using a stopwatch. I would like to remove the possibility for human error and create a script to test for us.

Currently, I can open a file and time how long it takes to execute the command with powershell  by using the following command:

```
Measure-Command {Invoke-Item C:\path\test.psd}
```

Is it possible to measure the actual time it takes to load the application and open the file using powershell? I've done quite a bit of searching and cannot find anything for this specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are going to run into a major problem, how do you define load?

Typically this is defined by time before the user is able to take an action, but knowing when that is is difficult for an automated system.

Either you will need to use a testing suite that is able to generate and monitor events (to tell when the form is ready to accept input) or generate an equivalent test to time that can be fully automate (for instance load the file and then exit without making any changes, don't know if you can do that with Photoshop however).

A final option that might work is a plugin which detects that it is a test and closes the form once it is ready, but I don't know enough about those programs to know if that is even feasible.

Comment: I figured that would be the response I would receive, but was hoping there was maybe some solution I was unaware of. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

With regard to Photoshop you could use Photoshop's com object to open the file and place timing statements before and after it (not tested). See the Adobe Photoshop Scripting for more info.

```
$ps = New-Object -ComObject Photoshop.Application
$beforeLoad = Get-Date
$ps.Open('C:\path\test.psd')
$afterLoad = Get-Date

"Loading time: $($afterLoad-$beforeLoad)"
```